# Compilation of Qualities of Krishna and Kansa

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana

I want, Compilation of qualities of Krishna and Kansa

collected from verses of various scriptures.

citing the particular verse-and writing Sanskrit word for that quality

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a forum for homework questions.